# HTML table Infinite Scrolling

Tags: html, html-table, salesforce-lightning

I am using HTML tables to display values, if the table has more than 100 rows it becomes slow how to do infinite loading in HTML table in salesforce ?

Comment: Please add your code too for better understanding and also state your desired output to get quick response from community.